# How to wait my custom command finish, then executing remaining Cypress commands

Tags: javascript, cypress, asynchronous-javascript

I'm getting trouble with Cypress asynchronous mechanism. I have a custom command that is placed in this file

```
class HeaderPage {

    shopLink = 'a[href="/angularpractice/shop"]'
    homeLink = ''

    navigateToShopPage() {
        cy.get(this.shopLink).click()
    }

    sshToServer() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Connecting')
        }, 5000)
        console.log('Connected')
    }
}

export default HeaderPage
```

The function sshToServer is simulated to pause 5000ms. So I want Cypress remaining test will be hold and wait for this function completed. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

```
import HeaderPage from "../support/pageObjects/HeaderPage"

describe('Vefiry Alert and Confirm box', () => {

    const headerPage = new HeaderPage()

    it('Access home page', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('url') + 'AutomationPractice/')
    });

    it('SSH to server', () => {
        headerPage.sshToServer()
    });

    it('Verify content of Alert', () => {
        cy.get('#alertbtn').click()
        cy.on('window:alert', (alert) => {
            expect(alert).to.equal('Hello , share this practice page and share your knowledge')
        })
    });
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting ?

Comment: Could you provide a runnable example? I tried to repro this with your code, but there are some issues with your HeaderPage class

Comment: @AlapanDas I didn't get the error. The problem is that Cypress complete its running, then after 5 seconds, I got the message from step 2 "SSH to server". It means Cypress didn't wait my function sshToServer() complete, it went through all remaining steps.

Comment: @konekoya you can download my codes here, the test script names "alert_confirm.js" https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZpeMD9jqP-89k5biolOGPvrueC0jXvbK/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can issue a new `cy.wrap` command with a value `null` and calling your async function in the `.then` function. Cypress will resolve that async function automatically and then move on to the next test.

First, you should convert your `sshToServer` method to an async(promise) function:

```js
sshToServer() {
  console.log('Connecting');
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Connected');
      resolve();
    }, 5000);
  });
}
```

Then, in your spec:

```js
it('SSH to server', { defaultCommandTimeout: 5000 }, () => {
  cy.wrap(null).then(() => headerPage.sshToServer());
});
```

Note that I have also used a bigger for the spec `defaultCommandTimeout` since the default timeout is 4 seconds which is shorter than your `sshToServer` method and would cause the test to fail if not using a bigger timeout.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. The result is same. All of tests have been completed, then after 5s, the log is printed in console browser :(

Comment: Yep, sorry. I didn't see the second log. I have updated the answer. And basically, the method should be a promise-based API and so Cypress can be aware of that

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked :) But I think the statement "console.log('Connected')" is not correct, it will be printed first.

Comment: Good catch. Updated

Answer (score -3):

Sorry for late answer but i think this is the easiest way to do it
`cy.wait(milliseconds)`